# Как вызвать данный шаблон?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

template< class T >
void selectSort(T* arr, int size)
{
    T tmp;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) // i - номер текущего шага
    {
        int pos = i;
        tmp = arr[i];
        for(int j = i + 1; j < size; ++j) // цикл выбора наименьшего элемента
        {
            if (arr[j] < tmp)
            {
                pos = j;
                tmp = arr[j];
            }
        }
       arr[pos] = arr[i];
       arr[i] = tmp; // меняем местами наименьший с a[i]
    }
```

}

Comment: Попробуйте при вызове темплейта в скобках указать тип, который передаете: ```selectSort<int>(arr,5);```. Тип указывайте в зависимости от того, какого типа указатель arr вы передаете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следующим образом :

```
 int arr[5];
 ...
 selectSort(arr, 5);
```